# @EJB inject from different jar

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm trying to inject a bean located in a different jar file then the bean i'm trying to inject it into. Both beans are just basic @Stateless beans with local and remote interfaces.
If i use the normal injection

```
@EJB
IBean injectedBean;
```

or

```
@EJB
IBeanLocal injectedBean;
```

i get a NullPointerException when deploying the application.

If i use:

```
@EJB(mappedName="Bean")
IBean injectedBean;
```

or

```
@EJB(mappedName="Bean")
IBeanLocal injectedBean;
```

everything works and JBoss throws no deployment errors.

I might mention i use JBoss 5.

The bean class i'm injecting is declared as:

```
@Remote
public interface IBean

@Local
public interface IBeanLocal extends IBean

@Stateless(name = "Bean")
public class Bean implements IBean, IBeanLocal
```

My problem is that as specified in the documentation the mappedName property is vendor-specific. Is there any other way i could get this to work?

**SOLVED:**

I managed to solve the problem.

The problem was that i tried to deploy both jars individually which meant that each would get it's own ClassLoader in JBoss so that they couldn't find each other and would return a NullPointerException when trying to inject the bean.

The sollution was to add the jars to an ear and add an META-INF containing an application.xml looking like this:

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd"
         version="1.4">

  <display-name>Simple example of application</display-name>

  <module>
    <ejb>ejb1.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>ejb2.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

I also had to change some JNDI lookups i made to match the new structure by adding the ear name before the classes: "ear-name/bean"

After this i just added the jars to the ear and everything deployed nicely.

Comment: Your `application.xml` root declaration is however wrong. You should be using an Java EE 5 compatible one instead of a J2EE 1.4 one.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Here is an example of application.xml for Java EE 5 and 6: http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2009/10/sample-applicationxml-java-ee-5.html

Comment: Can you give a sample code on your "ear-name/bean" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the local interface in order to have JBoss find the bean based on the interface only (assuming you're using EJB 3.0):

```
@Stateless(name = "Bean")
@Local ( IBeanLocal.class  )
@Remote ( IBean.class )
public class Bean implements IBean, IBeanLocal { ... }
```

Edit: IBean is a remote interface (see comment).

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention IBean is a Remote interface and IBeanLocal extends IBean and is a Local interface

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting your bean with `@EJB(beanName = "Bean")`

Not sure if it'll work, but we had a similar issue and it was caused by the lack of the `beanName` attribute.